# PHP catching mulitple type exceptions. Why does it behave this way?

Tags: php

I'm deepening PHP Exceptions. This code runs on php7

```
class MyErrorException extends ErrorException
{ /* stuff here */}

function uncaught_exception_handler($exception)
{ /* stuff here */ }

function uncaught_error_handler()
{ /* throws new MyErrorException */ }

set_exception_handler('uncaught_exception_handler');
set_error_handler('uncaught_error_handler');

$analyze_case = function($e)
{
    switch (get_class($e)){
        case 'Exception':
            echo "I've caught an Exception" . PHP_EOL;
        break;

        case 'Error':
            echo "I've caught an Error" . PHP_EOL;
        break;

        case 'ErrorException':
            echo "I've caught an ErrorException"  . PHP_EOL;
        break;

        case 'MyErrorException':
            echo "I've caught a MyErrorException"  . PHP_EOL;
        break;

        default:
            echo "I've caught something: " . get_class($e) . PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
};

echo "Case 8" . PHP_EOL;
try {
    throw new MyErrorException();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "I've caught an Exception" . PHP_EOL;
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    echo "I've caught an ErrorException" . PHP_EOL;
} catch (MyErrorException $e) {
    echo "I've caught a MyErrorException" . PHP_EOL;
} catch (Error $e) {
    echo "I've caught an Error" . PHP_EOL;
}

echo "Case 9" . PHP_EOL;
try {
    throw new MyErrorException();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $analyze_case($e);
};

echo "Case 10" . PHP_EOL;
try {
    throw new MyErrorException();
} catch (MyErrorException $e) {
    echo "I've caught a MyErrorException" . PHP_EOL;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "I've caught an Exception" . PHP_EOL;
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    echo "I've caught an ErrorException" . PHP_EOL;
} catch (Error $e) {
    echo "I've caught an Error" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

These are the results:

```
Case 8
I've caught an Exception
Case 9
I've caught a MyErrorException
Case 10
I've caught a MyErrorException
```

I don't understand:

- why case 8 and 10 mismatch
- more specifically, why in case 8) the thrown exception doesn't get caught by the `catch (MyErrorException $e)` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 8**

In case 8 the first catch block catches your exception, since your exception class `MyErrorException` extends from `ErrorException` and this extends from `Exception`. So it already gets caught in the first catch block.

Note: Your exception can get caught by `MyErrorException`, `ErrorException`, and `Exception`, since it is part of all these classes. But it can't be caught by `Error`.

**Case 9**

Again in case 9 it gets caught as it is also an `Exception`, but since you check the class in the switch satement you get `MyErrorException`. Since you have a `MyErrorException` exception.

**Case 10**

In case 10 it's the same as in 8, just that `MyErrorException` catches the exception now first instead of `Exception`.

Comment: so because of `set_error_handler('uncaught_error_handler');` which, in the end throws an Exception even in case of an error I should feel free to remove the `catch(Error $e)` block, right?

Comment: @wwr I think you are mixing something here. Setting your handlers for errors and exceptions doesn't have any relation to your catch blocks. Your custom error handler gets called if an error occurs and the custom exception handler when an uncaught exception happens. But you catch all your exceptions.

Comment: @wwr Yes if you throw an exception of `MyErrorException` in your error handler and you are always catching `MyErrorException` before `Error`, then you can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, in case 8 you get a `I've caught an Exception` message because your `MyErrorException` inherits (indirectly) from `Exception`. The object you're throwing being an instance of `Exception`, the first catch block is executed.

If you want to have specific catch blocks for subclasses of `Exception`, you should put them first.